# How to change the default config in MathJax?

Tags: javascript, mathjax, mkdocs, mkdocs-material

I am using mkdocs-material to build a website. In my mkdocs.yml file I have

```
extra_javascript:
  - javascripts/mathjax.js
  - https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6
  - https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js
```

where the last line is version3 of MathJax default config. Then I also have the mathjax.js file which I'm hoping to use to alter the default config. Right now mathjax.js looks like

```
window.MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [["\\(", "\\)"]],
    displayMath: [["\\[", "\\]"]],
    processEscapes: true,
    processEnvironments: true
  },
  options: {
    ignoreHtmlClass: ".*|",
    processHtmlClass: "arithmatex"
  },
  menuSettings: { 
    zoom: "Double-Click"
  }
};

document$.subscribe(() => { 
  MathJax.typesetPromise()
})
```

where I'm trying to use menuSettings to change the behaviour of zoom function so that it's active on a double-click. Building the website like so has no effect on the menuSettings and I cannot figure out what to do. What is the correct way of making it so zoom's behaviour gets altered?

A lot of the documentation for this function is for version2 of MathJax but I'm using version3 and I don't know how to work with it.

Comment: https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/configuration.html is specific to v3 though?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have removed `window.` and kept `MathJax = ...` and it still had no effect. I don't understand how to change zoom setting using that documentation. Further help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea how mkdocs does its thing, but that `window.MathJax` object needs to exist before the mathjax library itself gets loaded in, so without having looked it up, I'd imagine you can just put that in its own file, which I assume is what your `javascripts/mathjax.js` is: put a `console.log` statement in there, see if it even runs or not. And double check that you didn't misspell the file location, and if you're on a case-sensitive OS, double-check the string case.

Comment: The `menuOptions` block should be *inside* the `options` block.  It will be ignored if it is at the top level.